# .NET Core 3.1 incoming request timeout not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web API that I want to control how long it will wait until returning a 504 timeout error.

I added the following code to `Program.cs`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(opt => { opt.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); });
        });
```

With this I would expect any request that takes longer then 10 seconds to process to return a 504 error.

To test I added a `Thread.Sleep(100000)` as the first line in one of my controllers.

When I call the endpoint via Postman, it waits the full 100 seconds and returns a 200.

Why is it not throwing an error after 10 seconds?

Comment: Keep alive is not a request time out. İt determines the timeout when the connection is idle

Comment: Are you aware of any setting that will control request time out? Or is that only controlled by IIS/Hosting environment?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10079) GitHub issue about the request timeout. There is also [this](https://github.com/fooberichu150/request-timeout/tree/main/RequestTimeout.Demo) gist which has a middleware that implements a timeout.

Comment: If the answer below not works for you, pls share your test method, the return type of `IActionResult` is also important.

Answer (score 1):

According your requirement, I create a custom middleware.

**TimeoutMiddleware.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;

namespace Middlewares
{
    public class TimeoutMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TimeoutMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            await _next(context);

            var elapsedTime = DateTime.UtcNow - startTime;

            if (elapsedTime > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Register the middleware.**

The order is very important, you can register it as below.

[image]

**My test code.**

```
public IActionResult timeouttest()
{
    Thread.Sleep(11000);
    return Ok();
}
```

**My test result.**

[image]

Comment: This ruins the whole point of sending a `504` if you're still waiting for the entire request to finish just to overwrite the statuscode.

Comment: @NotFound Yes, of course I'm aware of this, I saw the op's description, so in the comment I just added, mentioning that using IActionResult might work for him.

Comment: @NotFound Because I reproduce the 200 status code mentioned by the op when I use eg string or int return types. Thanks for your reminder.